# Display all rows of data from the database

Tags: php, sql

I am developing a document management system, so far I'm able to log in and upload documents based on the user that's logged in. I've also managed to construct the code so it captures the records assigned to that user and display them in a table. So I am able to log in as different users and see what I've uploaded as them users individually. However, the only problem is that the script is only pulling out one row of data for each users, when there are multiple instances in the database. See the code below:

```
<!-- start of php code to query and display documents -->
        <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT upload.personalid, upload.file, upload.type, upload.size, person.personalid FROM upload inner join person on upload.personalid=person.personalid where person.username='$uname '") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
        $filedata= ($sql) ? mysqli_fetch_array($sql) : false;    
        {   
            if($filedata){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $filedata['file'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $filedata['type'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $filedata['size'] ?> Bytes</td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        else {
            echo 'No files found';
        }
        }
        ?>
<!-- end of php code to query and display documents -->
```

This all works fine, I just want it to display all the rows of data assigned to the logged in user, instead of one. How do I do this?

Thanks,

Sohail.

Comment: Sidenote: Your question's title contained a LOT of CAPS and was edited respectively. You've done that for all your other questions and is often frowned upon by the community. I suggest you keep titles as lowercase, or mixed case. If you're trying to get better coverage, believe me it doesn't help; it actually works "against" you.

Comment: Ever heard of loops? That could be useful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it so that you loop through each returned record like this:

```
<?php
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT upload.personalid, upload.file, upload.type, upload.size, person.personalid FROM upload inner join person on upload.personalid=person.personalid where person.username='$uname '") or die (mysqli_error($conn));
if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
    while ($filedata = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $filedata['file']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $filedata['type']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $filedata['size']; ?> Bytes</td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
} else {
    echo 'No files found';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your method and it's throwing me with this error: Line : 68,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: Updated my code. Not sure if it will help, or if there are other issues elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Not sure if you noticed, but you also have `'$uname '` a space in your username field, is that intentional?

Answer (score 3):

You're close. You need a `while` loop. Replace

```
 $filedata= ($sql) ? mysqli_fetch_array($sql) : false; 
 if($filedata){
```

With

```
while($filedata = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
```

Comment: one bracket too many ;-) => `while($filedata = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))`

Comment: Thank you for you response, I have changed the script but now I'm getting this error: 

Line : 46,   Error type : 4
Message : syntax error, unexpected '{'

Comment: some just can't figure stuff out for themselves ^

Comment: `while(($filedata = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)))` you don't need all those extra brackets Machavity.  `while($filedata = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))` will do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Am too used to Netbeans screaming about it

Comment: @Machavity Aahh, I see ;-)

Comment: This solution won't actually do the same thing as they want - there's an `else` there to catch "no records"

Comment: @Fred-ii- why don't you integrate it and show me then, seen as you're such a clever cloggs?